# Accessing something inside the object when you don't know the key

Tags: javascript

I am getting a following object

```js
{
  IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  }
}
```

Now, I want to access the value of thumbID inside it i.e. **d501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e**

But my root key seems to be dynamic/random (IuW1zvaSABwH4q), How can I access the value inside it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the values from object and than access the desired key.

```js
let obj =  {
    IuW1zvaSABwH4q: 
      {
        label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking', 
        thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
        schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set' 
      } 
    }
    
let op = Object.values(obj)[0].thumbId

console.log(op)
```

Comment: @brk The key is `IuW1zvaSABwH4q:` which is not known, thumID is consistent in the object I am getting

Comment: I think OP refers to the `IuW1zvaSABwH4q` key, not the `thumbId`

Comment: my mistake sorry

Answer (score 11):

You can use **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to transform it and **[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to get it and print it in the console.

```js
const obj = {
    IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
        label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
        thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
        schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
    },
    YuW1zvaSABwH7q: {
        label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
        thumbId: 'as90-f-b601-c8b1-4bd9958', 
        schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
    }
};
//for one object
console.log(Object.values(obj)[0].thumbId);
//multiple unknown keys
Object.values(obj).map(ele => ele.thumbId).forEach(th=> console.log(th));
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming there is only one property you could access it via the first property.

```js
const obj = { IuW1zvaSABwH4q: 
      { label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking', thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e', schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set' 
       } 
    };
    
console.log(obj[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)[0]].thumbId);
```

Comment: You can't assume that there's only one property when you're using `getOwnPropertyNames` because it returns enumerable and non-enumerable properties, and according to the docs, the ordering among enumerable and non-enumerable properties is not defined.

Comment: The assumption is made on the test data provided.

Comment: Use `Object.keys` like the docs say and you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `for..in` to iterate the object then check if this object has a key by name `thumbId`. This check will ensure that code does not throw error if the object does not have  `thumbId` key

```js
let obj = {
  IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  }
}


for (let keys in obj) {
  if (obj[keys].hasOwnProperty('thumbId')) {
    console.log(obj[keys].thumbId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Object.entries(obj)[0][1].thumbId
```

```js
const obj= {
  IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  }
}

//for(let o in obj) console.log(obj[o].thumbId);

let t=Object.entries(obj)[0][1].thumbId;

console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/)

```
let yourObject = {
  IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  }
}

_.pluck(_.values(yourObject),'thumbId');
// ["d501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e"]
```

You can also use `_.first` to safely access the first array element

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of using a combination of

`JSON.stringify()` and `split()`

```js
const obj = {
  IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  }
}
let thumbId = JSON.stringify(obj).split('"thumbId":')[1].split('"')[1].split('"')[0]
console.log(thumbId)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = {
  IuW1zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  },
    IuW2zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  },
    IuW3zvaSABwH4q: {
    label: 'Random Image of TypeScript not relavent to coworking',
    thumbId: 'd501-f-b601-c8b1-4bd995e',
    schemaType: 'xman-assets-image-set'
  }
}

for (var key in json) {
  if (json[key]) {
    for (var x in json[key]) {
      if (x === 'thumbId') console.log(json[key][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

I use two nested for to extract the thumbId.